# Error in sending mails in angular 2. Error says 'Unable to find module...'

Tags: javascript, angular, email, typescript

I want to send an email in angular 2 and I've installed emailjs and am getting some module errors. Can somebody help me with resolving these issues?

Here is my component.ts file

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import { DialogComponent, DialogService } from "ng2-bootstrap-modal";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { MapsAPILoader } from '@agm/core';

var email   = require("emailjs/email");

@Component({
    selector: 'modal-demo',
    templateUrl: './demo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./demo.style.min.css', './flags16.css'],
    providers: [ DialogService ]
})


export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http){}

    sendEmail(){

        var server  = email.server.connect({
          user:    "primaryusername", 
          password:"primpwd123", 
         //  host:    "smtp.your-email.com", 
         // ssl:     true
        });

        server.send({
            text:    "i hope this works", 
            from:    "primaryemail@gmail.com", 
            to:      "secondaryemail@gmail.com",
            cc:      "",
            subject: "testing emailjs"
        }, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });
    }

}
```

The following are the errors displaying when trying to load the page. Unable to open the page... I have all the files in the below shown errors in "node_modules/@types/node" folder.[image] Don't know why it is unable to recognize.

Comment: where have you placed `require("emailjs/email");` ? are you using cli ?

Comment: No it's not a cli project. and my emailjs is in node_modules and my component.ts in 'app/demo'. Did I include the wrong way?

Comment: you are using webpack then ?

Comment: yes am using webpack

Comment: check this [link](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#author-a-library) might help